# How paranoid should I be that the automatic package manager mechanism is going to remove packages that I use?

Tags: 11.10, apt

When I use the packaging tool, it "reminds" me to use **autoremove** to remove packages which are no longer needed.  But when I review the list, I see packages which I wish to keep.

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-tweak-tool is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ekiga libopal3.10.2 gnome-backgrounds gtali glchess gnome-games cheese gdebi
  gnobots2 gnome-icon-theme-extras libcheese-gtk20 libcheese1 gdebi-core
  libcapi20-3 gnibbles gnuchess-book libpt2.10.2 libcluttergesture-0.0.2-0
  gnotski gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90 libclutter-imcontext-0.1-0 libspandsp2
  cheese-common sound-juicer iagno glines libmx-1.0-2 libfolks-eds25
  gnome-contacts gedit-plugins liferea gnotravex gnect quadrapassel
  liferea-data gnuchess gnome-video-effects
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

For example, in the above list, gnuchess and gnuchess-book are identified.  I don't wish for them to be removed.

QUESTION:  Are these metapackages that I need not fight (with apt) to defend from removal?  Will I lose the ability to play glchess?

> NB. I used gnome-tweak-tool as an example in the commandline, knowing that
>   it was already installed.  This is irrelevant to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to be paranoid, you just need to read and comprehend what `apt-get` is telling you. Obviously, if you remove `glchess`, you will lose the ability to play `glchess`!

At some stage you must have removed a package (probably a [metapackage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages)) which depends on some or all of the packages you see.

To figure out which metapackage this might be, you can use `apt-rdepends`. This tool can look up "reverse-dependencies", or packages which depend on a given package.

For example, for the package `gnome-backgrounds`:

```
$ apt-rdepends -r gnome-backgrounds
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-backgrounds
  Reverse Depends: gnome-core (>= 1:3.0+1ubuntu1)
gnome-core
  Reverse Depends: gnome (= 1:3.0+1ubuntu1)
gnome
  Reverse Depends: gnome-desktop-environment (>= 1:3.0+1ubuntu1)
gnome-desktop-environment
```

This shows that `gnome-backgrounds` is depended upon by a single package, `gnome-core`, which in turn is depended upon by `gnome`, which in turn is depended upon by `gnome-desktop-environment` which no other packages depend upon.

Now you can find out about these packages:

```
$ aptitude show gnome-core gnome gnome-desktop-environment
```

You will see that these are all meta-packages, and on your system at least one has been removed. You can then:

- Try to `apt-get install` the 'lowest' dependency, in this case `gnome-core`. However this may pull in additional packages that you don't actually want to install (*read what apt-get says, don't just hit enter*).
- If you don't want everything the meta-packages would install, and you want to keep all the packages, just run `aptitude keep-all`. This will mark the outstanding packages as 'installed', and `apt-get` will stop reminding you about them.
- If you only want some of the packages, you can `apt-get install` them before running `apt-get autoremove`. You'll have to read the package descriptions to decide which ones you want.

I think the main point here is that `apt-get` is just a tool. It doesn't know what you *really* want, it just does what you tell it. For this reason you should *never* blindly trust it to do the 'right thing', because often this is not the same as what you told it to do! This is doubly important to keep in mind when running `sudo` commands, since it's so easy to do catastrophic damage to your system.

Comment: That was an excellent explanation!  Thank you very much.  Yes, last night I had deleted gnome-screensaver (which required me to also remove the gnome and gnome-core metapackages) in order to overcome gnome-screensaver's defiance on my running xscreensaver... long story... anyway, this is what has led to the current state.  I will do an aptitude keep-all.  It would have taken me many moons to figure out what you have taught me with your answer.  I am grateful to you and to AskUbuntu!

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I actually did an `apt-get install` on most of the packages.  I use most of them.  This has saved me a great deal of effort as I am on a tether-only hookup and things cost me plenty (time and/or money)!  You explain things excellently and are extremely valuable to the community.